# Is there a hidden significance of the PS3 loading screen / background?

Tags: ps3

According to the below, the PS2 loading menu changed based on the number of and duration of games played.

[image]

Is there anything similar for the PS3?

Comment: IIRC, the background color on the default theme change according to the clock. The sparkles move according to your XMB movements as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The background color of the default XMB theme changes every month, while the brightness changes according to the time of day. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XrossMediaBar#PlayStation_3):

> The XMB's default background color changes depending on the current month of the year, and it changes brightness depending on the time of day. Major color changes occur on the three days before the 15th and 24th of each month, while the color gradually changes between those dates.  [image]